# Do vector-like notations for polynomials exist?

Tags: polynomials, notation

Polynomial equations might be written as dot product of factors and powers of `x`.
For instance, quadratic equation:

$$
ax^2 + bx + c
$$

might be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 \\ x^1 \\ x^0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So to write this even shorter we can put all `a`, `b` and `c` into some kind of vector $\vec{a}$:

$$
a_2 x^2 + a_1 x^1 + a_0 x^0 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2 & a_1 & a_0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 \\ x^1 \\ x^0
\end{pmatrix} =
\vec{a} \begin{pmatrix}
x^2 \\ x^1 \\ x^0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

But what to do with vector for `x`? Is there some kind of special notation that represents a vector of powers of `x` for a given dimension?
Like this:

$$
\vec{a} \begin{pmatrix}
x^2 \\ x^1 \\ x^0
\end{pmatrix} =
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}^2
$$

This way it is possible to write polynomials much shorter, like $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}^2$ or $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}^5$.

So, do vector-like notations for polynomials exist?

Comment: have you had linear algebra?

Comment: @WillJagy how this answers my question?

Comment: I never seen a notation like this, but always you can use the notation you want if you defined before. If your quenstion is if this can be usefull, well... save time for sure... but i dont see another advantage. However, i am not expert in polinomials haha

Comment: If You have factors and variables separated You can do something like $\vec{a}\vec{x}^2 + \vec{b}\vec{x}^2 = (\vec{a} + \vec{b})\vec{x}^2$. Or You can write a factor matrix for a spline like $A \vec{x}^3$.

Comment: What would "existing notation" mean? That we do not get confused by $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{x}^2\,?$ Please adopt the following principles: math is not a programming language where some committee supervises what compiles and what not. If you want to use a notation that you find convenient, explain it before you use it once and for all.